# Simple htaccess Rewrite Rule (remove .php)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a simple website that uses .php files, like

```
www.domain.com/about-us.php

www.domain.com/contact.php
```

Now I'd like to create a Rewrite Rule that turns these URLs into:

```
www.domain.com/about-us/

www.domain.com/contact/
```

So basically just remove the .php ending. And I'd like to exclude some files from this rule, like "mailer.php" for example. How can I get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a rewrite rule for that. Just add this link on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

#### Read more about it: [httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html)

#### UPDATE

To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you :) Seems to work, but, will there be any problems with Google??? Obviously I want Google to index only the non .php version ;)

Comment: see UPDATEd code above for 301 of old links of `.php` to non-php.

Comment: Nice, that's what I needed. Thanks a million! :))

There's only one thing I noticed:
www.domain.com/contact does work perfectly with the css/js/image links, but www.domain.com/contact/ (with a slash at the end) doesn't. 

Is there a simple way to fix it or do I have to use absolute links everywhere?

Comment: Always better to use absolute links. OR else you can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: Great! Works perfectly now